# ERROR install (yum install git) git in CentOS version 6.5 I have this error. Does anyone know how to correct it?

Tags: centos6

ERROR install (yum install git) git in CentOS version 6.5 I have this error. 
Does anyone know how to correct it?

```
Failed to set local, default environment in C
Complements: fastestmirror, presto, remove-with-leaves, security
Loading mirror speeds from the cached host file
epel / metalink | 18 kB 00:00
* base: mirror.cs.vt.edu
* epel: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
* extras: ftp.linux.ncsu.edu
* updates: mirror.cogentco.com
Nubityd | 2.9 kB 00:00
base | 3.7 kB 00:00
extras | 3.4 kB 00:00
mysql-connectors-community | 2.5 kB 00:00
mysql-tools-community | 2.5 kB 00:00
mysql56-community | 2.5 kB 00:00
Updates | 3.4 kB 00:00
"Error in requested URL returned: 410 repo" - [Errno 14] pycurl ERROR 22: http://repo.varnish-cache.org/redhat/varnish-3.0/el6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
Test another mirror
Error: Can not retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: barnnish-3.0. Check your route and try again
```

Answer (score 1):

Go here for your answer

```
http://repo.varnish-cache.org/redhat/varnish-3.0/el6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
```

Says this repo is no longer in use.

> Deb and RPM repositories now at Packagecloud The official packages for
>   Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS and Red Hat are now located in repositories at
>   Packagecloud.io. Users of repo.varnish-cache.org repositories will
>   have to change their hosts over to the new repository configuration.
>   For details see the below sections for the distribution in question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running WHM/cPanel by chance? If so- try running this:

```
yum install git --disableexcludes=main
```

See if that works for you.

Comment: it's an e3 aws (amazon), it's not cpanel